# Finding elements in a vector that are duplicated or that are not in another vector

Tags: r, match

I have the following situation:

```
vec1  <- c("A", "B", "D", "C", "E", "A", "C")
vec2 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "F")
```

First question: which one is duplicated ? - answer "A" and "C" for vec1, 0 for vec2

Second question: Identify which is vec1 but not in vec2, irrespective of order (answer "E")

or vice versa (answer "F")

```
which(vec1 !=vec2)
which(vec2 !=vec1)

[1] 3 4 5 7
Warning message:
In vec1 != vec2 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

which is not what I expected....

Comment: @ttmacer, `setdiff` suggested below is equivalent to `unique(which(!vec2%in%vec1))`, which is more appropriate here.

Comment: If you had read the documentation for R, including the bits about comparing vectors by element and the description of the 'which' function, it would have been _exactly_ what you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements in vec1 that are duplicated:

```
vec1[duplicated(vec1)]

[1] "A" "C"
```

Elements in vec1 that are not in vec2:

```
vec1[is.na(match(vec1,vec2))]

[1] "E"
```

And vice versa:

```
vec2[is.na(match(vec1,vec2))]

[1] "F"
```

Answer (score 5):

For the first question, try `?duplicated`

```
vec1.dup <- duplicated(vec1)
unique(vec1[vec1.dup])

[1] "A" "C"
```

For the second, try `?setdiff`. You want the values of vec2 that are not in vec1.

```
setdiff(vec2, vec1)
[1] "F"
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your (second)  question is  ..Why? ( I do see that you have gotten good answers to the correct ... How? )

```
which(vec1 !=vec2)
which(vec2 !=vec1)
```

Both  return

```
[1] 3 4 5 7
```

The answer lies in major part in the warning message you did not include:

```
Warning message:
In vec1 != vec2 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

When dyadic operators like "!=" work on vectors, the recycling rules take over so the longer of the two vectors determines the "range" for the comparisons, and the shorter one gets extended by recycling. You end up testing:

```
> c("A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "A", "B") != c("A", "B", "D", "C", "E", "A", "C")
                                         #.... extending shorter one ^^^^^^^
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> c("A", "B", "D", "C", "E","A", "C") !=  c("A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "A", "B")
#.... extending shorter one ^^^^^^^
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```